# Start one loop where another one stopped

Tags: loops, fortran

I have a loop that internally unrolls a sparse matrix vector multiplication. We calculate this using a diagonal approach for the upper right matrix with leads to a different length for each diagonal.

The unrolling then happens linewise, i.e. I calculate several diagonals at once, until the shortest diagonal reaches the end of the matrix. Then I want to calculate the remaining diagonals with another loop with decreased unrolling length.

This leads to the problem that the second loop needs to start where the first loop has ended. I'm now stumbling upon a construct like the following (very simplified):

```
do diag=1, nDiagonals-3, 4
    ! here be dragons
end do

do diag=diag, nDiagonals-2, 3
    ! here be smaller dragons
end do
```

In Fortran the do index has to be set in the control clause, in contrast to C where `for(;n<m;==n)` is a possible loop control clause. But is the construct above with `do index=index, upperbound` valid? Or are there better approaches for this kind of loop index handling?

Comment: if it bothers you for readability you can always do `start=diag;do diag=start,..`  Personally I'd put a comment explaining you are relying on the exit value being the next value. Standard but not immediately obvious.

Comment: @george: Thanks for this advice. Actually, this is what I ended up with. I think, in terms of readability, this is the minimum one can do. Additionallz, the compiler will (hopefully) delete the intermediate variable during optimization, so it won't hurt anway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't see anything syntactically wrong with your code, nor do I think you are doing anything dangerous if legal.

After the end of the first loop `diag` will have the value it would have if the loop continued for one more iteration.  This behaviour is defined by the standard. Given the snippet

```
do diag = start, stop, stride
    ! do stuff
end do
```

at the end of the loop `diag` has value equal to `(start + n*stride)` where `n` is the smallest integer such that `(start + n*stride)>stop`

So, for a loop such as

```
do diag = 1,10,3
    ! do stuff
end do
! now diag == 13
```

and you can carry on using it to start the next loop as you outline.

What you can't do, in Fortran, is adjust the value of the do-variable inside the loop, the compiler behaves as if it establishes the loop limits at the first encounter with the `do` statement.

Comment: Thanks. Modifying the do-variable inside the loop is known to me, I was just wondering if `diag=diag` is a "common" or at least a valid expression.

Comment: It's valid, but not something I've ever seen.